# How do you tell if Google translator is active?

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I'm adding Google Translate links to my website, but I want to run some JavaScript based on the current language being viewed.  Using JavaScript, is there a way to determine the following:

1. Is the site currently being viewed through the Google Translate frame?
2. If so, can I tell which language is being viewed?

Comment: It seems like an AJAX request is made when I translate on Chrome, but I'm not sure whether it's possible to know this from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its built into Chrome and just wraps your site so you will have no idea.  You can check the HTTP Accept-Language header to see what region they are coming from so you can localize it, but thats about it.

Comment: Well, that's too bad. Haven't worked with frames much, but I guess this makes sense.